# How to leash a horse to a Minecart?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying to leash a horse with a minecart but I am really bad at UUID. I have tried various commands but they are all totally wrong.

Is it possible to leash a horse to a minecart? I have watched some tutorials on internet but most of them is about leashing 2 mobs together with world edit or something like that. Is it possible to do it with a command? Something like:

```
/summon horse ~ ~ ~ `{Leashed:1b,UUID:1,Leashedto:UUID:2}`
```

Comment: [You can lead a horse to a minecart, but you can't make him ride it](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/you-can-lead-a-horse-to-water-but-you-can-t-make-him-drink)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is actually different than I remember. It is like this:

```
/summon horse ~ ~ ~ {Leashed:1,Leash:{UUIDMost:<ID>,UUIDLeast:<ID>}}
```

You have to calculate the ID parts like [this](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.de&sl=de&sp=nmt4&tl=en&u=https://minecraft-de.gamepedia.com/UUID&usg=ALkJrhiNy56KUY0Gy0G1qWGqbJpZjE_cyg#Umrechnung_UUID_in_UUIDLeast_und_UUIDMost) ([archive](https://translate.google.de/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fminecraft-de.gamepedia.com%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DUUID%26oldid%3D528737%23Umrechnung_UUID_in_UUIDLeast_und_UUIDMost&edit-text=)). (Careful: Google translated)